# Why doesn't script recognise empty src?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that checks if an img `src` is empty:

```
 if (document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').src == "") {
 document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').style.display = 'none';
  }
```

The src is empty but the code does not hide the image? Is there a problem that I missed?

Comment: Remove the `== ""` part and see what happens. Is `'featuredIconImage348790'`  really the HTML `id` attribute for that image? Is that even an image?  HTML please.

Comment: Can you show an HTML example / jsFiddle?

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').src)`?

Comment: Ah, does that image element exist at the time you run the script? If not, you probably have an error in your console waiting to be read

Comment: @ERN check the answers bellow, if the answer help vote it up, if the answer is really what you loking for mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `getAttribute()` instead :

```
if (document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').getAttribute('src') == "" ){
     document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').style.display = 'none';
}
```

When you have no `src` attribute like :

```
<img id="featuredIconImage348790" />
```

You have to make condition like `== null` because `getAttribute()` method will return `null`.

And if you have empty `src` attribute like :

```
<img id="featuredIconImage348790" src=""/>
```

You can make condition that check if empty `== ""`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wasn't sure why this made a difference until I saw the other answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

The `src` of the `img` is considered to be relative - in this case a relative empty string, so it becomes prefixed with the hostname, as the snippet below demonstrates. Try `getAttribute('src')`.

```js
document.write('"' + document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').src + '"');
document.write('<br>');
document.write('"' + document.getElementById('featuredIconImage348790').getAttribute('src') + '"');
```

```html
<img id="featuredIconImage348790" src="" />
```